# Rabbitmq management api sample json response

Tags: json, api, rabbitmq

I am trying to get all the information that RabbitMQ Management API provides.

I have my own rabbitmq set-up done locally in a clustered environment, I am able to fetch the api response.

I am just not sure if I have pulled all the available information. I need some sample json response of the API(or detailed documentation) about what all data does the API return, so that I could compare it.

I see a similar question on stackoverflow, but the links provided there were not available anymore.

It would be great if anyone could provide some useful links.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find all the API(s):
https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html and in 
detail:

https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_10/priv/www/api/index.html

I am pretty sure that is no a documentation with `json` responses detail

Comment: Thanks Gabriele, I have already looked at that content. I looked up extensively online, and understand that there is no documentation or sample JSON response available anywhere.